# Loading assents in a local flutter library in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, package, assets

I am developing a local personal flutter library with some icons to share with some of my apps.
Those are vectorial images with .svg extension that are stored in lib/assets/src/. To make the image loading more efficient (according to the docs of flutter_svg package), I compile them with vector_graphics_compiler and put them in lib/assets/dist.
Here is the code to get the icon

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:vector_graphics/vector_graphics.dart';

class MyIcons {
  MyIcons._();

  static const assetsFolder =
      "absolutepath/to/dist";

  static get home => const AssetBytesLoader (
        "${MyIcons.assetsFolder}/home.svg.vec",
      );
  static get group => const AssetBytesLoader(
        "${MyIcons.assetsFolder}/home.svg.vec",
      );
}

Widget icon(AssetBytesLoader iconData, {double size = 18.25}) {
  return SvgPicture(
    iconData,
    height: size,
    width: size,
  );
}
```

to access home, for example, I use
`icon(MyIcons.home)).`
here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter: 
  assets:
    - lib/assets/dist/group.svg.vec
    - lib/assets/dist/home.svg.vec
```

But when I import the library to a project and try to access one icon, I get:

```
"FlutterError (Unable to load asset: 'path/to/asset'.
The asset does not exist or has empty data.)"
```

But if I copy and paste the path to the file explorer, it actually points to a file

Comment: Are you specifying the package name when trying to load the asset? See: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#from-packages

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!